# Getting response data in Volley OnErrorResponse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-volley

I am hitting API on the server. It is working perfectly but when I run it in my app I am getting volley onErrorResponse along with data . I am not able to understand how it is possible. I am sharing code and error image. Please check.

```
      private void callProductsApi() {

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = Constants.GET_PRODUCTS;


    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();


    try {
        params.put("token", Constants.token);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.e("login_response", response.toString());


                    pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(Splash.this, R.string.some_error_occured, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });


    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            100000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The api should return success code which is 200, 201 and so on response. if it returns 
other response in line of 400 or 500 it will display the correct json but in error method.